# Wordpress automatically adding <!-- --> html tag around PHP code

Tags: php, html

I was managing a site, taking over from a previous administrator. With his last breath, he changed something on the site, precisely on the login section:

http://www.spiritualresponse.com/login/

I don't know if intentionally or not, but the login form has vanished. This is an ASAP task to fix it, so what I can gather, the PHP code, that calls on the sidebarlogin plugin, gets auto commented. This has not happened previously and I have no clue what is causing it. Where I input the code, it is without the "" tags, but when it renders, the php gets commented out.

I did not find any solution on google since searching for "auto commenting/ comment" detailed problems gives very different problems/solutions in the category of wordpress.

All help would be appreciated, I hope this is some kind of "switch this and everything will be alright" problems :)

----EDIT1-----

My bad in asking the question badly. This "system" or configuration worked previously, I have the exec-php plugin installed and it is working. Something got changed and now it is NOT working :(

Comment: you can reach the login via: http://www.spiritualresponse.com/wp-login.php

Comment: Oh, you missunderstood I know, how to reach the admin pane. I am worried by the "average" visitor, I want to place their login page back where they left it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 'login'  menu button points to a page 
- to execute php code in pages you need a plugin such as the ['exec-php' plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/exec-php/) or similar.

in the meantime use http://www.spiritualresponse.com/wp-login.php to login

Comment: Hi Michael! I already have the exec-php plugin installed and it is actively running. Maybe I phrased my question badly, my bad. It WORKED PREVIOUSLY. SOMETHING went wrong and now IT stopped working :(